# Cancel timertask javafx

Tags: exception, javafx, timer, timertask

I´m using this code to perform an action after 10 seconds:

```
    public void seconds() {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                 Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            panebuttons.setVisible(true);
                            timer.cancel();
                         }
                });
            }
        },10000, 100); //10000 = 10 seconds to show the buttons

    }
```

This is the instance :

```
Timer timer= new java.util.Timer();
```

I need to stop the timer at any moment. If i stop the timer while is runing ,everything is ok.But if I click the button with the timer.cancel(); line,after the timer ends,I get an exeption.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.**

the exption is correct!!. the timer was cancelled after ten seconds.BUt if i want to show the buttons before the timer reach the ten seconds?

Any idea ??

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Disable the button in the `TimerTask`?

Comment: The program has a pane with butons,one of these buttons make the pane invisible to see other options.IF nothing hapens the pane with buttons is visible again after ten seconds.If I dont want to wait ten secons to see the "Main" bottons I Press the "back" button and show it again.I need the timer running each time the user press the button "show".